# how to create a token in laravel for rest api?

Tags: php, laravel

My code sample is below,

```php
try {
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
    ],);
        $toke = $user->createToken()->accessToken;

    return response([
        'message' => 'Successfully Registered!',
        'token' => $toke,
        'user' => $user
    ],400);

} catch (Exception $e) {
        return response(['error'=> $e->getMessage()],401);
}
```

I didn't find any wrong my code but error showing like this:

```
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Models\User::createToken(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\reactwithlaravel\app\Http\Controllers\AuthController.php on line 50 and at least 1 expected in file C:\xampp\htdocs\reactwithlaravel\vendor\laravel\passport\src\HasApiTokens.php on line 64
```

So please anyone can teach me or give me hint or full code share me
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So , Here is what you are missing.

```
Error says you need at least one parameter to call the function "createToken()"
```

Here is sample code copied from docs:

```
use App\Models\User;   
$user = User::find(1);
// Creating a token without scopes...
$token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
// Creating a token with scopes...
$token = $user->createToken('My Token', ['place-orders'])->accessToken;
```

Please refer to the following URL:

[Laravel passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport)

Hope it would help you a bit.

Comment: Thank you. I got it

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [Laravel Passport docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens) you need to pass a name to the `createToken` method.

```php
// Creating a token without scopes...
$token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it

Comment: @anis Great you solved it. Feel free to mark any reply as answer to close the question.